# jquery :contains giving error: jquery-1.12.3.js:1502 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: contains("sys")

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement a filter which will filter "pre" html element when text matches with what user is entering in an input html element.

But it doesn't seems to work when i try to check it with what user is entering, but works if i hardcode the text to be searched.

Here's my js script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#input")
        .change( function () {
            var filter = $(this).val();
            if(filter) {
            $("#list").find("pre:contains(\""+filter+"\")").show()
            $("#list").find("pre:not(contains(\""+filter+"\"))").hide()

            } else {

            }
            return false;
            })
        .keyup( function () {

            $(this).change();
            }); });
```

If i hardcode the "filter" to some string in "pre" elements it works.
for eg: one of the string has "sys" in it, so if i hardcode like:
                `$("#list").find("pre:contains("sys")").hide()` : it hides the element.

Comment: Try removing `\"` and `\"` `$("#list").find("pre:contains("+filter+")").show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second line for hiding,

```
$("#list").find("pre:not(contains("+filter+"))").hide()
```

is converted to

```
$("#list").find("pre:not(contains(sys)").hide()
```

which throws unrecognized expr for `(contains(..))`

---

It should be with `:` for `contains()` - final evaluation to `:not(:contains(...))`

```
$("#list").find("pre:not(:contains("+filter+"))").hide()
//                       ^
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrk7pdc7/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

check the quotes, you don't need to escape the quotes:

```js
$("#input").change(function() {
  var filter = this.value;
  $("#list").find("pre:contains(" + filter + ")").show() // show the filtered one
            .siblings('pre').hide(); // hide others.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='input'>
  <option>Filter it...</option>
  <option>where</option>
  <option>sys</option>
</select>
<div id='list'>
  <pre>what</pre><br>
  <pre>when</pre><br>
  <pre>sys</pre><br>
  <pre>where</pre><br>
</div>
```

---

The issue is the pseudo selector `:contains()` usage. You have missed a `:` just before the second line where you want to hide the other elements *(which can be done without doing that.)* Use chaining with `.siblings('pre')` and just hide with `.hide()`. Check the answer above.